# Custom logo/wallpaper change

Tags: powershell

I would like to write a PowerShell script which will change:
1 - Boot windows logo
2 - Login windows wallpaper 
3 - background windows

I want to store 3 different image in a USB and start the script so that the changes apply at the next login.

Trying to understand what is the best way to do taht. thought about PowerShell

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and also read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Stack Overflow is not a free script writing service. Your own research and code attempts are expected. Edit the question to include your code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: Hi @Theo, thanks for replying. I just want to know what is the best way to do it before i research more info. I am not aspecting a ready code from the community.

Comment: please specify the ways that you've tried so far and mention the exact problem.

Comment: The best way to do this is Group Policy Management. Are you on a domain? This isn’t a great task for Powershell.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answers. I am not in a Domain, I simply want to deploy a windows for private customer on my shop. I just want to customize windows after deployment.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if I understood the question in the right way.

To be honest , I do not know how to do that in a Powershell script, however, you can use [Hack BGRT](https://github.com/Metabolix/HackBGRT/releases) to change your boot logo.
For the rest, I suggest you to make the changes manually.

Sincerely, naschemaa.